# How to implement click the certain area to do to action?

Tags: android, facebook, sliding

[This](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo/blob/master/SlidingMenuDemo/src/grimbo/android/demo/slidingmenu/SlideAnimationThenCallLayout.java) is an example of facebook sliding menu.

When sliding, there is 20% space user can see which is similar with facebook. Facebook implements it with clicking anywhere of this 20% and the menu is slide back.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing that is as following with OnTouchListener on your activity. You can detect exactly where is touched on the screen.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidTestActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
  LinearLayout main;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    main.setOnTouchListener(this); // you need to set the touch listener for your view. And every element around the detection area.
  }

  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    if(e.getX() <= main.getWidth() / 5) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "In the %20..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return true;      
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

You also need to id your main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it seem like did not work for me. Even i did not set any condition but i click any area of the layout the animation did not start

Comment: the 20% area i still got other component, however i click the component within 20% area, it will do the component own function instead of start animate

Comment: if you have any other layout, image view or anything else at that area you need to add listener for them with setOnTouchListener..