# How to align the curved images in a xml layout?Is it possible to align programmatically in java?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Following are the images which i have to implement in my project:
[image: this image at the top]

[image: this image at the left]

[image: this image is at the bottom]

and finally it should look like this:
[image: it should look like this with equal gap with each of the images with textview inside it]

Help would be praiseworthy and thankx in advance.

Comment: I can suggest that you play with `RelativeLayout` and `margins/padding` as you need to add images over each other.

Comment: why dont you use all these as one image with a transparency?

Comment: @hrskrs i have played with it,but its not coming as desired

Comment: @NaderAyyad we can"t use transparency as we have use these images as a button

Comment: @sid_dude what do you mean? you can use them as one image and then create the onClicklistener on the container layout... if on click is not handled by the children its then passed on up the view hierarchy to its parents.

Comment: @Nader it can"t be done like that bcoz each time view changes when the imageView is clicked

Comment: @sid_dude you can listen to a click on a part of a View. This doesn't matter if the image changes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700362/how-to-implement-click-the-certain-area-to-do-to-action

Comment: What is the purpose of keeping this image??

Comment: this image act as ImageButton......and each of this individual button shows a different layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with `RelativeLayout` and `margins/padding` as you need to add `images` over each other. Here i give you an example with your own images:

*(notice that i added `width/height` manually and didnt care about `naming` as it is just for test purpose for giving you a clue on how to achieve it. Hence if you play with `height/width` of `imageViews`, you must play with their `margins/padding` too)*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tt"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ll"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rr"/>

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is just a text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where:

- `tt` is the curve on top
- `rr` is the curve on the right
- `ll` is the curve on the left

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort but it"s not done as i have already done in this way.........exact gap should be maintained between the ImageView with a TextView inside.....

Comment: @sid_dude as i said this is just a test purpose to show you a way on how to achieve what you want. I also `putted Text in the middle for you(see edited answer)`. If you want something more detailed you mention it in the question. Whatever you asked here you have. You can give exact gaps inside them also, but we are here to guide and not to solve something you have not even tried for.Anyway check edited answer for a guide on how to do that too.

Comment: i have definately rechecked it brother.....but the right curve and left curve is not maintaining equal gap.....i"m trying it hard.....can you please give it a little more try by taking 170dp of curve size ......venture in hope you can help me out.....thankxxx in advance,brother...

Comment: @sid_dude thats the best i can do it for you. If you want images perfectly aligned you can play around with them. Otherwise you have to find another strategy for implementing it

Comment: U CAN SEE THE DIFFERENCE YOURS IS MORE COMPACT ONE...aLTOUGH YOU HAVE DONE IT NICELY....i"m stiLL wORKING on IT TO GET THE PERFECT RESULT.

Comment: @sid_dude as i said, we are here to help and not to solve the details. So if the answer helped you you can upvote, if it solved your problem you can accept. Mine is compact as this is just to show you how to do it. You have to increase `leftmargin of top curve` and leftMargin of `right curve` to expand the space if you want. But that is your job. Me as `SO` user, i did my job.

Comment: Presently i"m working on it as per the requirement.....and i have to solve it by hook or crook..... 
Anways, THANKS FOR YOUR EFFORT FRIEND.....YOU WILL GET An UPVOTE FOR YOUR ANSWER Soon though its not perfect ..... only after the requirement is fulfilled or  i finish the work.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Sorry for bad naming.,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dummy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/a"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/a"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/a"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.1"
                android:background="@drawable/a"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dummy2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/a"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dummy3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/a"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dummy1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/a"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/a"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/a"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.8"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.8"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/a"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.05"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/a"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayou"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/d"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible" >

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Linea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/d"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/c"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```